# Why $\mathbb S^1\times \mathbb S^1$ is isomorphic to the torus?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Could someone explain why $\mathbb S^1\times \mathbb S^1$ is isomorphic to the torus ? I recall that $\mathbb S^1=\{ x^2+y^2=1\mid x,y\in\mathbb R \}$. To me it would be more something like the picture.

[image]

Comment: What is *your* definition of the torus?  For me, $\Bbb{S}^1 \times \Bbb{S}^1$ is the definition of the torus.

Comment: For me it's $C/f$, i.e. the cylinder where you glue the two circle of boundary.

Comment: But anyway, haw can $\mathbb S^1\times \mathbb S^1$ (as draw in my picture) can be the torus ?

Comment: @Rick You've drawn two copies of $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ for some reason. $S^1$ is the result of gluing together the ends of the interval $[0,1]$. Similarly, $S^1 \times S^1$ is the result of gluing together the ends of the hollow tube $S^1 \times [0,1]$.

Comment: Yes sorry, I was thinking about the intersection of the violet tube and the blue tube. It isn't $\mathbb S^1\times \mathbb S^1$ ?

Comment: @Rick I think you may be incorrectly generalizing from the case $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ where the two copies of $[0,1]$ are on the $x$ and $y$ axes respectively.  In that case $[0,1] \times [0,1] = ([0,1] \times \mathbb{R}) \cap (\mathbb{R} \times [0,1])$.  If you were to do that for $S^1 \times S^1$, then since $S^1$ is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$, you need $S^1 \times S^1 = (S^1 \times \mathbb{R}^2) \cap (\mathbb{R}^2 \times S^1)$.  You seem to have replaced the $\mathbb{R}^2$'s with $\mathbb{R}$ in your diagram.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idea is that a torus is like a circle of circles :) A nice picture that helps the imagination can be found on wikipedia:

[image]

So the idea behind $\mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1$ is that one needs to provide two coordinates $(r,s) \in \mathbb S^1 \times \mathbb S^1$ to specify a point on the torus: $r$ tells you which red circle you want to be on (by specifying a point on the violet circle) and $s$ tells you where on this red circle you want to be.

Obviously this can be made more rigorous but I think this will already help with the intuition.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 6):

Think of a unit square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ with opposite sides identified.  We identify $[0,1] \times \{0\}$ with $[0,1] \times \{1\}$ so that $\{t_1\} \times [0,1]$ is a circle for all $t_1 \in [0,1]$.  In particular, this first gluing gives $[0,1] \times S^1$ (which is a cylinder).  Similarly, doing the second gluing, we identify $\{0\} \times S^1$ and $\{1 \} \times S^1$ so that $[0,1] \times \{t_2\}$ is a circle for all $t_2 \in S^1$.  Visually, you're gluing the two ends of a cylinder together to get the torus.  This is $S^1 \times S^1$.

Also, it might be natural to think of $S^1$ as $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ and the torus as $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$.